# Monitor is not displaying maximum and minimum water in interface in Netlogo

Tags: variables, output, netlogo

I have  tried and explored the already answered question on this forum before posting my question.I am building a model for water use by farmers. I want farmers to use water own by them and then from their patches and then want to have changed water variable of patches, farmers and  as a global variable sum of both surface water of farmers and patches. and I expect to see output as maximum and minimum water at every tick. But my monitors and graphs displays same value. I am unable to find the mistake please guide.Codes are given below with picture of GUI.Thanks.

```
globals [TW  well-depth]; total water
breed [farmers farmer]
farmers-own [SWA] ;surface water availbility
patches-own [ wtd GW ] ;water table depth and Groundwater

to setup
  clear-all
  create-farmers num-farmers [
    move-to one-of patches
    set SWA  random 12
  ]
  ask patches [
    set WTD 2
    set GW 3
    set pcolor green
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask farmers [
    update-water
  ]
  tick
end

to update-water
  ifelse swa < 5 [
    ask patches in-radius 1 [ 
      set pcolor blue
      set TW gw + [SWA] of myself
    ]
  ]
  [
    ask patches in-radius 1 [ 
      set gw  gw - random-float .0005
      set well-depth wtd / gw 
    ]
    set tw swa
  ]

end
```

Interface setup:

[image: Interface setup]

Plot setup:

[image: Plot setup]

Hi, I want to build a model for timeline of farmers cropping in a year and update yearly farmers income, wealth, water available, water use etc.For that I have tried to build a model considering suggestions from previous answer to this post. I need to completely solve the given issue. If I take access-water in my codes as a global variable. my maximum and minimum value of water get changed but it remains same when I stop the model. But as per suggestion if I take excess-water as farmers-own then excess-water graph displays a constant line and a constant maximum and minimum water. I need to see fluctuations although I have tried to include water use in my model.Expected output of my model majorly will be water use/ access-water, groundwater and surface water.Please recommend corrections.
Thanks

```
      Globals [ potential-buyers  year season  TAWS TGWU TWR   rprice wprice  excess-water ]
    Breed [rfarmers rfarmer]
    Breed [pfarmers pfarmer]
    Breed [wcrops wcrop]
    Breed [ccrops ccrop]
    Breed [rcrops rcrop]
    rfarmers-own [
  savings
    tubewell
    wyield
    ryield
    land
  CRPDCSN
   WR-wheat
  SWA-rabi
  GWA pumping-on?
   seasonality
  input-cost
wealth
  wrevenue
  wincome
  wwealth
  allowed-pumped-water
  wr-rice
  income-1
  SWA-kharif
  income-2
  rincome
  rrevenue
  rwealth
]
patches-own [Gwater well-depth
WTD]

    to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor green
    Set WTD 3 + random-float 18.005

  set Gwater  GW / WTD 
   ]
  create-rfarmers no-of-rfarmers [set shape "person"
                                  set color brown
                                 move-to one-of patches
                                 set land 12
                                 set wealth 1000 + random 500
                                set input-cost 5 + random 3
                                set tubewell 1
                                set wr-wheat 10 + random-float 12   
                                set SWA-rabi 4 + random-float 6.6    
                                set SWA-kharif 6 + random-float 9.6  
                                set wr-rice 18 + random-float 15
                                set GWA   pumping-on?

                                set wprice 1.300 + random 5.0  
                                set rprice 1.500 + random 1.00 
                                set wyield 25 + random 20
                                set ryield 40 + random 20
                                                               ]
Reset-ticks
end

to go
ask rfarmers [cropping-decision
;use-GW
update-wealth-w
 ]
tick
update-timeline


end
to cropping-decision
    ifelse  wealth > input-cost and land > 2 and ticks mod 2 = 0
                 [ set CRPDCSN "wheat"
                   if wr-wheat < SWA-rabi [ use-GW]
                   set seasonality "Rabi"
                    ]

                    [set CRPDCSN "rice"
                     Set seasonality "Kharif"
                    go-2]

    end
to use-GW
    ifelse (SWA-rabi - wr-wheat) < 0  [set pumping-on? true

                                                       ask patches in-radius 4 [ set wtd wtd + random-float 1.00005]
                                                      set input-cost input-cost  + 0.0005  * ( wr-wheat - SWA-rabi) / wtd ; changed from 200 to 20 t0 .05
                                                      set gwater gwater - random-float 0.0005 / wtd
                                                      set excess-water SWA-rabi - wr-wheat + sum [gwater] of patches in-radius 1
                                                      if excess-water > 0 [sell-buy-accesswater]] 


  [set pumping-on? false
    set wyield wyield - random-float 0.0005
  set excess-water SWA-rabi 
  set input-cost input-cost  - random-float 1 ]

end

to sell-buy-accesswater
                       set potential-buyers other rfarmers in-radius 4 with [(excess-water <= 0)] 
                      ask potential-buyers [set input-cost input-cost + 0.0005 * ( wr-wheat - SWA-rabi) / WTD
                                             set wyield wyield - .0005 ]
                                             set income-1 0.0005 * excess-water
                                             set wyield wyield + random-float .000005
                                             set excess-water excess-water - [excess-water] of potential-buyers

end
to update-wealth-w
set wrevenue wprice * (wyield * land)
              set wincome wrevenue - input-cost * land
              set  wwealth wealth + wincome + income-1

end
to update-timeline
 if ticks mod 2 = 0 [set season "Rabi"   set year year + 1
   set wprice wprice + 1 ]
;Ask rfarmers [set SWA-Rabi SWA-Rabi - random-float .0005]] ;to incorporate effect of climate
  if ticks mod 2 = 1 [set season "Kharif"
    set rprice rprice + 1]
 ; ask rfarmers [Set SWA-Kharif  SWA-kharif - random-float .001] 

end


to go-2
ask rfarmers [use-GW-R
;buying-selling-GW-R
;lsell-buy-water-r
update-wealth-r
update-wealth
]


end

 ;;;;;;;;;;; Same procedure is adopted for rice;;;;;;;;;;;;
to use-GW-r
  ifelse (SWA-kharif - wr-rice) < 0  [set pumping-on? true
                                                      ;set Gwater  (gwater - (SWA-rabi - wr-wheat))
                                                     ;set GWA 10 + random-float 10
                                                      set input-cost input-cost  + .0006  * ( wr-rice - SWA-kharif) / wtd ; changed from 200 to 20 t0 .05
                                                      ask patches in-radius 4 [ set wtd wtd + random-float .005 ]
                                                     set excess-water ( SWA-kharif - wr-rice + gwater )
                                                      if excess-water > 0 [sell-buy-accesswater-r] ] ; + GWater]

         [set pumping-on? false
          set ryield ryield - random 2]

end

to sell-buy-accesswater-r
  set potential-buyers other rfarmers in-radius 3 with [(excess-water <= 0)] ; and  (wtd >= allowable-lm-pumping)]
                ask potential-buyers [set input-cost input-cost + 0.0005  * ( excess-water) / WTD
                                      set ryield ryield - .005 ]
                                      set income-2 0.5 * (excess-water)

end

to update-wealth-r
 set rrevenue (rprice * ryield * land)
              set rincome rrevenue - (input-cost * land)
              set rwealth  rincome + income-2

end

to update-wealth
  if ticks mod 2 = 1
  [ set wealth  wealth + .0005 * (rwealth + wwealth) ]
end
```

here is the interface setup of the model
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking your plot to show the `TW` of turtles, but `TW` is a global variable- there is only ever one value for `TW`. When you ask for `[TW] of turtles` you are returned a list of identical values (whatever `TW` currently is) whose length is the same as the current number of turtles. So, say for example that you have 5 turtles and a `TW` of 11; when you ask for `plot max [TW] of turtles` you are really asking Netlogo to plot the maximum of `[ 11 11 11 11 11 ]`, and the same is true for the minimum.

Another problem with this setup is that since `TW` is a global variable, every time you run `update-water`, you are having each patch modify `TW`. In your model, whatever `TW` is currently set to will be overwritten by whatever patch is last called. You may want to rework your `update-water` to be specific to farmers or patches, rather than using a global variable.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to plot- do you want the minimum and maximum water available to a farmer? That might be something like this:

First, add `FW` to the `farmers-own` variables, then try this modified `update-water` procedure:

```
to update-water

  ifelse swa < 5 [
    ask patches in-radius 1 [
      set pcolor blue
    ]
    set FW swa + sum [gw] of patches in-radius 1
  ]
  [
    ask patches in-radius 1 [
      set gw gw - random-float 0.0005
      set well-depth wtd / gw
    ]
    set FW swa
  ]

end
```

When you now `show [FW] of turtles`, you get a list like `[10 17 6 19 18 7 9 15 5 10]` instead of a list of identical numbers. Now try plotting with the same plot update command you used before, but with `FW` instead of `TW`. If I'm way off, please let me know what you're wanting to plot.

**Edit:**

Simplistic example of water use, where the farmers each "use up" the `swa` available to them. Replace the `update-water` procedure with the one below and run your model- you should see farmers start to use up their `swa` until their `swa` is less than 5, then they will start to use up the nearby patch `gw` until it is all used up.

```
to update-water

  ifelse swa > 5 [
    set swa swa - random-float 0.5
    set FW swa 
  ]
  [
    set swa 0
    ask patches in-radius 1 [
      if gw > 0 [
        set pcolor blue
        set gw gw - random-float 0.25
      ]
      if gw <= 0 [
        set gw 0
        set pcolor black
      ]
    ]
    set FW swa + sum [gw] of patches in-radius 1
  ]

end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.you right and to the point. I got your point for global variable. I have replaced FW as per your suggestion. It's displaying constant minimum and maximum. What possible changes can be made in the codes to see variations in above values?

Comment: Well, in the model as is there is no code to actually "use" the water- the farmers are just noting what water is available to them. Since the `swa` of farmers and `gw` of the patches are not changing, you will get constant values. I think you'll want to program actual "water use" in some way- I'll edit my answer with a very simplified (unrealistic) example.